# How to use second router as bridge for wireless extension?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, bridge

I have researched a lot online, and thought I understood the just of using my NETGEAR RangeMax Duo Wireless-N Router WNDR3300 as a bridge to my Zyxel AMG1302-T11C. However, every post online seems to be hardware-specific.

I want my Zyxel router to be the master bridge.

The current configuration I have tried is:

Zyxel Router:

[Broadband Settings 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCRtS.png)

[Settings Continued 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qX6R.png)

[Settings Continued 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMmiG.png)

Netgear Setup:

[Wireless Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFOnG.png)

[Repeating Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fms0p.png)

[Internet Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Zst4.png)

For the Zyxel, if I enable 'Bridge and Routing Mode', I lose internet connection, and the two routers do not connect.

For the Netgear, when I input a 'Passphrase' (same password as the Zyxel), the 'Keys' are populated, and I can wirelessly connect to the router using one of the keys. Once I apply the 'Internet Settings', I am unable to connect to the router's admin UI.

I am able to use the Netgear as an extension, if I connect its internet port to one of the LAN ports of the Zyxel, but I do not own an ethernet cable long enough to make use of any range. So, wireless is my only option. I tried to follow [this](https://www.techadvisor.co.uk/how-to/network-wifi/router-repeater-3633135/) as a guide.

What am I missing? Is this possible with my routers?

Comment: Any specific reason to be using WEP as the encryption mode?

Comment: WEP is the only supported encryption for the Netgear to enable repeater functionality. As far as I understand, the encryption method between device and the secondary router does not matter, because the master router is fully encrypted.

Comment: No, that understanding seems completely wrong. Clients connecting to secondary APs _only_ communicate with "their" APs and do not know anything about the encryption used by the main AP. And the reason repeater mode on the Netgear requires WEP is because due to the way it works, it has to use the same encryption method in both directions – both for accepting clients and for connecting to the main access point. (That's one of the reasons modern products no longer use this type of "repeater" mode; significant speed loss being the other.)